# Variables wont update immidiately after clicking submit button

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic "onButtonSubmit" function that is called when a form submit button is clicked.

The form works and the "ticker_symbol" does update because I can console.log() it out. The problem is though that the "console.log()" doesn't print out what is in there until I click the form button a second time. The first time it is just an empty string. So, for some reason, this is not updating immediately.

Does anyone know how to make sure that ticker_symbol is set the first time the function is called? What is going wrong with this?

Below is a snippet of the functions with the issues and related functions:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
        this.state={
           // stock: '',
        //  shares: '',
        //  items: []
        input: "",
        ticker_symbol: '',
        share_count: '',
        stocks: []
    }
  }

 onInputChange = (event) => {
   this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onInputChange2 = (event) =>{
    this.setState({input2:event.target.value});
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () =>{
    this.setState({ticker_symbol: this.state.input})
    this.setState({share_count: this.state.input2});
    console.log(this.ticker_symbol);
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <StockInputForm 
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 
          onInputChange2={this.onInputChange2}
          onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit} 
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the value would show on the second click is because setState is asynchronous. When clicking a second time the async operation would (probably) have finished, which is why the value would exist.

Its possible to attach a callback to the setState method so that you could safely do whatever you like and be sure that the value does exist.

```
this.setState({ticker_symbol: this.state.input},() => console.log('this will happen after setState has finished');
```